# Android - Open URL from json results

Tags: android, json

I have a question about URL got from JSON details.

This is my code:

```
JSONObject currentEarthquake = couponCategoryArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject properties = currentEarthquake.getJSONObject("campaign");
            String name = properties.getString("name");

            String promo_code = currentEarthquake.getString("promocode");

            String goto_store = currentEarthquake.getString("goto_link");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(goto_store));


            CouponCategory couponCategory = new CouponCategory(name, promo_code, goto_store);
            couponcategory.add(couponCategory);
```

From JSON, I get 3 fields: name, promocode and goto_link.

goto_link is URL.

My intent is click the link on goto_link field to open the link in the browser.

I added an intent under goto_link String.

Some suggestion to code it correctly?

Comment: How does your url look like?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. For example: https://www.storename.ext

Comment: That does not look like an url. That is only a name with extension. What kind of protocoll would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this.

Your URI starts with HTTP or HTTPS like this: http://www.google.com

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(goto_store));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. I tried this solution but look the error I got:
https://ibb.co/bRxhvD8

Comment: please delete " ". 
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(goto_store));
startActivity(browserIntent);
Inte

https://i.imgur.com/N4p1sNZ.png

Comment: Done: https://ibb.co/nmZNJWb
For the solution 2 and 3, I get it: https://ibb.co/bRxhvD8
If I select solution 4 (rename reference): https://ibb.co/bB17x2d

Comment: I can support you by remotely. I hope to see full-code.

Comment: IS this code extended "Activity", "Fragment", "Adapter"?
Looks like Adapter...

Comment: No problem for the full code. How can I do?
Yes, it is an adapter.

Comment: Teamview or anyDesk do you have?

Comment: I have bought, TM and AD

Answer (score 0):

You can open a link in the browser like this:

```
   yourButton.setOnClickListener {
               val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
               intent.data = Uri.parse(goto_store)

               if (intent.resolveActivity(requireContext().packageManager) != null)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void openWebPage(String url) {
        try {
            Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No application can handle this request. Please install a web browser or check your URL.",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How is you goto link formatted ?
anyways an answer from @MarkB solves it

```
string goto_link = "http://www.google.com";
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(goto_link));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

incase your link doesnt have the `http://` part

```
string goto_link = "www.google.com";
if (!goto_link.startsWith("http://") && !goto_link.startsWith("https://"))
   goto_link = "http://" + goto_link;
```